# How can I get a node endpoint that allows me to filter transactions?

Tags: web3.py

Hi guys please I need help. I'm trying to filter transactions from address that are not on my database using web3.py but I haven't been able to find a node endpoint provider that allows me to continuously filter the transactions. Each time I try to run it, it works for a few minutes or seconds and then it stops. Please how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi dev advocate a at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

Try [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/), we allow filtering using `web3.py`.

The docs also have [API example requests](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_newpendingtransactionfilter)!

Comment: Thanks so much.... I'll check it out